# how do I convert an array to an long int and back to an array

Tags: c

You are given an integer N. Find the digits in this number that exactly divide N my code gives me a timed out message i.e. Terminated due to timeout or CPU time limit exceeded (core dumped). here is my code`enter code here`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int T, cnt, digits1, digits2, rem;
    long long x;
    char N[11];

    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%10c", N);
        int x = (atoll(N));
        digits1 = x;
        while (digits1 != 0)
        {
            digits1 = x/10;
            cnt++;
        }
        // char buffer[cnt + 1];
        for(int j = 1; j <= cnt; j++)
        {
            rem = x % N[j];
            if (rem == 0)
            {
                digits2++;    
            }
        }            
        printf("%d", digits2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your program? Link in the Help Center: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: digits1 should never go to zero making the first inner loop infinite.  You can't divide by zero, therefore, dividing two numbers will never equal zero.  Obviously, if "x" is less than 10, digits1 should be zero.

Comment: You should compile your program with warnings enabled (and acted on). `x` is declared twice, and even if this allowable by your compiler within scope, having two different variables of the same name in the same function is bad. There are uninitialised variables, also you should research what `scanf()` does with a `%c` type - it does not fill the array.

Comment: @superultranova: Incorrect. Integers are being used here so if `N=2` then `digits1 = 2/10` which results in `digits1 = 0`. Even if `digits1` was a float, it is possible to divide and get zero due to limited precision.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework.

I'll give some pointers.

Once you have the input chars converted to an actual `int` or `long` (or `long long` in your case), do NOT muck around with digits - especially in base 10. If you're going to do anything like that then you may as well leave it in `char` array form. This bit is not needed:

```
while (digits1 != 0)
{
    digits1 = x/10;
    cnt++;
}
```

You have uninitialised values. Don't assume that everything is automatically initialised to zero. Sometimes you get lucky... but often you won't.

This looks good:

```
for(int j = 1; j <= cnt; j++)
{
    rem = x % N[j]; //not quite right N is ASCII
    if (rem == 0)
    {
        digits2++;    
    }
}
```